# How do I use the cruise control?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In Saint's Row 2, I made extensive use of the cruise control for those drive-and-shoot missions. I seem to remember being told I could use cruise control in Saint's Row 3, but I can't seem to figure out how. How do you work it?

Comment: If you have the ability to play this game co-op, let me tell you it is very, very worth it.  Having one guy on the wheel and one on guns makes the "drive by" missions you're talking about so much easier.

Comment: FOR COOL?  CAPS LOCK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [Xbox](http://webassets.thq.com/Manuals/SRTT/SR3_360ONLINE_MAN.pdf) and [PS3](http://webassets.thq.com/Manuals/SRTT/SR3_PS3_Online_MAN.pdf), it's "Down" on the D-Pad.  On the PC, by default, it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.  On consoles, this button is also used to start the streaking diversion and to take screenshots.  On the PC, by default it's the "Crouch" key.

To further describe the functions of this button on consoles:

- You'll need to tap the button twice while not wearing any clothes for streaking
- Tap it once while moving forward in a car to engage cruise control.
- Tap once to make a screenshot, but this requires camera mode to be on, which is an option in your phone menu.

These functions are [mapped differently](http://images.onesite.com/thq.com/gameManuals/Saints_Row_The_Third/SR3_MAN-PC_en.pdf) on PC.

The feature's not well publicized, I first learned about it from a random tooltip about 10 hours into the game.  The paper manual that came with the game has the buttons listed, which is about all the info that's in the manual, period.

Comment: That's odd. I'm three hours in on the PS3 version and I think I've seen the cruise control tip dozens of times while cruising around. I do make heavy use of my GPS, however, and rarely find myself opening fire, so perhaps that's why?

Comment: The tooltips are a bit random, so it might have just been my bad luck.  It could also be that I ignored it.  :)